# WordPress scheduled task to delete rows older than 48 hours

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up a cron job to delete rows older than 48 hours. I've never done this before and decided to try and make a WP scheduled task. Below is my code in my `functions.php` file. I am assuming my delete line/query is wrong. Any help would be appreciated; or if there is an easier way I am open to that too. Thanks.

```
add_action('init','es4u_delete_old_videos');
add_action('es4u_delete_video','es4u_delete_video_func');

function es4u_delete_video_func() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    DELETE * FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE start_time < DATEADD(HOUR,-48,GETDATE());
}

function es4u_delete_old_videos(){
  if(!wp_next_scheduled('es4u_delete_video')) {
       wp_schedule_event (time(), 'hourly', 'es4u_delete_video');
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what I have now, but tables still aren't deleting. Any idea?

```
add_action('init','es4u_delete_old_videos');
add_action('es4u_delete_video','es4u_delete_video_func');

function es4u_delete_video_func() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'DELETE * FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE start_time < DATEADD(HOUR,-48,GETDATE());';
    $wpdb->query( $sql );
}

function es4u_delete_old_videos(){
  if(!wp_next_scheduled('es4u_delete_video')) {
       wp_schedule_event (time(), 'hourly', 'es4u_delete_video');
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look this - [wp-cron](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/6783/wp-cron#t=201610122011104648126).

Comment: @stweb Okay, thanks. Say I follow the `wp_schedule_event()' example, I place my code within `es4u_delete_video_func()` into `do_this_hourly()`. That fixes the setup, but I know my code is clearly wrong; I'm not sure how to write the delete *... query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mysqli` functions you can use the built in WordPress class [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to do some of the work for you. WordPress creates a global `$wpdb` object that you can use.

```
function es4u_delete_video_func() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM awdwp_webinar_orders WHERE start_time < DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -48 HOUR )';
    $wpdb->query( $sql );

}
```

Comment: I'd also point that the VCP's delete query is written "as is in SQL" in PHP directly. Since this is PHP, not SQL, one has to use certain methods to send a query. Methods like `mysqli` or others.

Comment: @jrod Ah, okay awesome, I see how to do that now. I've done limited stuff with `$wpdb`. Thank you. So if I replace my function with what you wrote, that should work every time someone visits the page? Does it make a different if my `start_time` column is a `datetime` type?

Comment: You should be able to update your function with what I have provided as long as your SQL query is correct. You are setting the cron job to fire every hour so it won't fire for every visitor but if when a user visits the site an hour or more has passed since the last time the cron job fired it will fire again.

Comment: @Jrod Hmm my query must be wrong because the tables aren't updating. I feel now I am so close but just missing something small.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice this before but your query is wrong. You shouldn't use an asterisk between DELETE and FROM and your use of DATE_ADD is incorrect. I've updated my answer with the correct query.

Comment: @VCP Can you give me some more info? Is the query not working? Is the cron job not firing? Any errors?

Comment: @Jrod I guess I'm not really sure; I added the code in my edit but the rows are still in the table. How can I troubleshoot? I guess I am little over my head with this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct table names and field names in the query? Is your table actually `awdwp_webinar_orders` or is it prefixed? As far as I can tell this should be running fine. Create a copy of your database and try running the query there with phpmyadmin. If it works fine you know the query is working. After that use a plugin like WP Crontrol to view the cron tasks you have and make sure you are seeing your `es4u_delete_video` job listed.

Comment: @Jrod Thanks. It's working. It was my mistake; I had placed your code in an older function I was trying. I downloaded WP Crontrol and saw it there and ran it. So everything's good. One last question. Am I able to display a count down timer using datetime? I want to create a timer to display to the user how much longer they have left. I assume I can't because of the datatype. Do I need to change it? And if so, does that change my query? Thanks.

Comment: @VCP The datetime field is fine. You may need to change it to a different format for your timer but that should do able with all the different PHP functions available for working with date/time. If you need help implementing a timer please create a separate question for that. If this answer has helped you solve your problem please mark it as correct. Thanks.